# How can I find statistics on Tomcat 6 server connectionTimeout failures?

Tags: tomcat6, connection-timeout, netstat

I am running Tomcat 6 and have a connectionTimeout set to 3000 (3 seconds).

I am trying to find out, on the Tomcat server itself, is there any way for me to know how many connection timeouts are occurring?

Comment: The server has no idea how many of the clients are failing to connect to it. That's all happening elsewhere.

Comment: But the connectionTimeout, is where a client gets a connection, but never sends data within a specified time. So it seems to me that the server is aware of the number of connections that where requested, but then never sent data... How else would you know if there was a denial-of-service attack?

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat 6 there isn't anything the explicitly counts connection timeouts. (In later versions you could enable debug logging which would provide details of every failure). What you can do is use JMX to look at the error count. Every failed request increments the error count. Be aware that any response code >=400 will increment the error count so there is lots of legitimate traffic that could trigger this.

In a JMX browser (e.g. JConsole) you need to look at the errorCount attribute of `Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=http-8080` (assuming an http connector on port 8080).

For a more accurate figure you could use the access log to count up the number of requests with >=400 response codes. The errorCount less that figure should be close to the number of connection timeouts in 6.0.x. In later versions that won't work because the access logging was improved to capture more failed requests.